# iDangerous Swiper not detecting swipe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm creating a image marquee for a mobile site that uses iDangerous Swiper plugin and have run into a issue when trying to use it. Following the set up based on the site, [found here](http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/api.php), I built my demo page to the exact spec of their demo. But for some reason, the function isn't running and I cant swipe to the next div. Being a mobile site, I'm using Jquery and Jquery Mobile. Any ideas?

```
<body>

<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">

      <!--First Slide-->
      <div class="swiper-slide">
       <img src="img/1.png" width="200" height="118">
      </div>

      <!--Second Slide-->
      <div class="swiper-slide">
       <img src="img/2.png" width="200" height="118">
      </div>

      <!--Third Slide-->
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="img/3.png" width="200" height="118">
      </div>

      <!--Fourth Slide-->
      <div class="swiper-slide">
       <img src="img/4.png" width="200" height="118"> 
      </div>

      <!--Fifth Slide-->
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="img/5.png" width="200" height="118">
      </div>      

  </div>
</div>

<script>

$(function(){
    var mySwiper = $('.swiper-container').swiper(options);
})

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Where are you setting up the "options" variable that you are passing in?  Also, if you could set up a jsfiddle.net test it would be helpful for troubleshooting.

Comment: I can't get it to work either, though having followed the exact instructions on the 'usage' page. Setting up a swiper div looks real easy though. Too bad there's no support from iDangero.us...

Comment: I also have a `<script>` tag that imports jQuery, so that's not the reason for disfunctioning.

Comment: yeah i've just all together abandoned the swipe navigation for something else. I get that its not too hard to set up but im not sure where it doesnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use buttons for Swiper you need to use .swipeNext() and .swipePrev() methods on mySwiper object like:

```
<!-- Add somewhere in HTML your buttons:-->
<span class="button-next">Next button</span>
<span class="button-prev">Previous button</span>
<script>
$(function(){
  var mySwiper = $('.swiper-container').swiper();
  //"Next" button - some HTML element with "button-next" class
  $('.button-next').click(function(){mySwiper.swipeNext()})
  //"Prev" button - some HTML element with "button-prev" class
  $('.button-prev').click(function(){mySwiper.swipePrev()})

})
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

iDangero.us here!:) Your HTML is correct. But what is "options" in your example? this should be an object with parameters or if you want to use default options then just remove "options" word from your example like: var mySwiper=$('.swiper-container').swiper()

Comment: AWESOME!! Thank you so much, didn't realize that that was the problem. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Quick question, Say i wanted to use buttons for the swiper as well as touch gestures, what would the function be called, `onClick="??"`

Comment: Thanks! Could you also say how 3Dflow is activated? I have added `tdFlow: {}` and its options within the Swiper options, just like the example on iDangero.us, but unfortunately it doesn't make it 3D. Does it require another statement that 3Dflow needs to be applied to the swiper?

Comment: Didn't you forget to include additional 3DFlow's JS and CSS files?